# Excel, Active X checkbox "tick" to "cross"?

Tags: excel, checkbox, activex

Is there a way to add cross "X" instead of tick. in a check box. ? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Gary's Student's suggestion, I came up with the following hack:

- Size a cell to a small square
- Format it as follows:

  - Align text in center (horizontally and vertically)
  - Top and left border thick dark grey, bottom and right border thin light grey
- Hide the gridlines in the worksheet
- Place the following code in the module of the worksheet with the cell:

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private mRngOld As Range
  Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
      Dim rng As Range
      Set rng = Range("B2")

      If Application.Intersect(Target, rng) Is Nothing Then
          Set mRngOld = Target
          Exit Sub
      End If

      If rng.Value = "X" Then
          rng.Value = "-"
      Else
          rng.Value = "X"
      End If

      If Not mRngOld Is Nothing Then mRngOld.Select
  End Sub
  ```

If you now click on the cell (in the example, it is `B2`), you'll toggle between `X` and `-`.

This is how it'll look:

[image: Example screenshot]

And here's a link to the example [workbook](https://mega.co.nz/#!fdxDSLhQ!OftKc0d2MKQzUIS0E9xAoEX7LSJMmw7YHq89Kzi1kpk).

Comment: thanks for the example, I cant change my excel becos i have lots tick boxes lots of merged cells. i will keep it in mind for future works.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say, but the ActiveX checkbox in Excel does not support such a feature.

Comment: It is possible, using VBA, to toggle a cell to display either an **X** or nothing upon a mouse click.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: great idea - I implemented it with a Selection change event, see my other answer.

Comment: Nice job Peter!  I am thinking about a hyperlink based solution......I'll think some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can use wingdings and use the lowercase o and x.  A lowercase o with print an open box.  A lowercase x with print a box with an x in it.